# Chrome mobile camera 100% screen size?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, android-camera

I'm using the following code to access the camera and display the stream.  For some reason it is 100% width but only probably 70% height. What is the best way to make it fill the screen?

**HTML**

```
<video autoplay class="screen"></video>
```

**CSS**

```
video {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid blue; //so I can see the size of the element
}
```

**JS**

```
var video = document.querySelector('video');

function startStream() {
    // Get access to the camera!
    if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        // Not adding `{ audio: true }` since we only want video now
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { facingMode: "environment" }  }).then(function(stream) {
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            /*video.play();*/
        });
    }
}

startStream();
```

This ends up looking like this:

[image]

---

**Update**

I changed the `.video` CSS to the following:

```
video {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

This makes it fill the screen, however, now the container is wider than the screen which is causing some overflow issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like adding a container fixed the issue.

```
<div id="videoContainer"><video autoplay class="screen"></video></div>

#videoContainer {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    video { height: 100%;}
 }
```